# How to profile R6 class functions?

Tags: r, r6

R6 class functions are anonymous so profiling information is lost. For example:

```
library(R6)
library(proftools)

Test <- R6Class("Test",
  public = list(
    fn = function() pause(0.3)
  )
)
obj <- Test$new()

#
# Profile
Rprof(line.profiling=TRUE)
replicate(10, obj$fn())
Rprof(NULL)
png('profile-self.png')
plotProfileCallGraph(readProfileData(), score='self')
dev.off()
```

gives the following profile information:

[image: profile graph]

How can I profile these functions effectively?

Comment: I opened an issue on the R6 github repository https://github.com/wch/R6/issues/71

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a recent version of R-devel (since [this commit](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/e8395b3)), it will output `obj$fn` instead of `<Anonymous>` in the profiling data. This should be in the next release of R (3.3.0?).

Comment: Time to check this?